# Computer specs good enough to run 1080p movies?

Tags: compatibility, hdmi, specifications, high-definition

Im trying to run 1080p movies on my computer and watch em over my new full hdtv, tho, my i already tried once, my computer (using vlc) makes the software crash, here's my specs:
Windows Vista
Processor: AMD turion 64x2 mobile tech 2.00 GHZ
3.00GB Ram
Graph card: NVIDIA GeForce 8400M GS

Would appreciate it very much if someone helped me out with this

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CoreAVC](http://corecodec.com/products/coreavc) to accelerate decoding via CUDA.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error message or error code?

Have you tried updating your video card driver?

What version of VLC? 1.1.2 came out not too long ago, and the changelog notated some crash fixes (although, I've found the 1.1.x series to be a little unstable so far).

If none of that helps, revert back to the latest 1.0.x version of VLC.  If that doesn't work, revert back to the latest 0.9.x version.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, crashing doesn't mean your computer is too slow. It means that something is wrong with the drivers, application or otherwise. If the software was all good, then the video would at least play - if the hardware is too slow, it will just play choppily.

What is the format of video? Is it h.264? If you have the latest NVIDIA drivers, it is able to accelerate certain types of HD content.

I have a similar configuration, and I'm able to display 1080p provided that I shut down ALL background applications and services, because that hardware is BARELY able to do 1080p. You are better off with something at least 2-core 2.5 GHz and an NVIDIA 8600 or AMD 5xxx-equivalent.